# dynamic generated variable replace using preg_replace

Tags: regex

```
$string = "I have the string like "this is the [image1] of the home. this is the [image2] of the home"
```

i want `[image1]` to be replace like `"uploads/1.jpg"`, `[image2]` be `"uploads/2.jpg"`.

Please help me

Comment: I can't imagine `image` is the same in every case. Or that `1` or `2` is either. Be specific, show the real sample text. If it is the same, you don't need a regular expression.

Comment: $text = "新人モデルの成長を追ったドラマ、シュートミー！<br /><br /><br />[image3]<br /><br /><br />モンタナ出身のエミリーは、モデルを夢見てロサンゼルスへ。<br /><br /><br />[image6]<br /><br />"              here [image] remains same only the change in number 1 to 12 that is dynamic. that [image] is to to replace by real image like "upload/news/1.jpg".

Comment: here $text is description field of the news table  in database which contains images names in format like  [image1],[image2],[image3], along with text. I need to find these images and replaced by the original image like "uploads/news/1.jpg","uploads/news/2.jpg","uploads/news/3.jpg" and display the page with text and image.

Answer (score 1):

REgex:

```
\[image(\d+)\]
```

Replacement string:

```
uploads/\1.jpg
```